# Chrome indicator not being displayed in the system tray anymore

Tags: unity, google-chrome, indicator, chromium

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity front end. Last time I checked, google chrome stable used to have an indicator icon on the system tray. If chrome was closed using the cross button, it would minimize to the tray. But now that indicator is not being displayed anymore. Clicking the cross button is completely quitting chrome. How can I bring that feature back?

Answer (score -1):

Start Chrome again and right click on the icon in the system tray. In the opening menu activate the background process.

Comment: The tray icon isn't being displayed even when chrome is running.

Comment: I already have the background process enabled. And the tray icon is missing as mentioned by OP.